# Mesclar dois arrays

Tags: php, array

Tenho os *arrays*:

```
$tamanho = ['P', 'M', 'G'];
$quantidade = [1, 3, 5];
```

O resultado final teria que ficar assim:

```
$final = [
            ["tamanho" => 'P', "quantidade" => 1],
            ["tamanho" => 'M', "quantidade" => 3],
            ["tamanho" => 'G', "quantidade" => 5]
        ];
```

Pensei em usar o `array_merge`, mas ele me retorna isso:

```
{"P":"1","M":"3","G":5}
```

E eu preciso dos índices "tamanho" e "quantidade", pois vou usar um `foreach` para inserir esses dados no banco de dados, então preciso expecificar o tipo de dado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode utilizar `array_map()` para combinar os valores dos arrays `$tamanho` e `$quantidade` em um novo com os indices desejados:

```
$tamanho = ['P', 'M', 'G'];
$quantidade = [1, 3, 5];

$novo = array_map(function($t, $q){return array('quantidade' => $q, 'tamanho' => $t); }, $tamanho, $quantidade);
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [quantidade] => 1
            [tamanho] => P
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [quantidade] => 3
            [tamanho] => M
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [quantidade] => 5
            [tamanho] => G
        )

)
```